# Angular2 + Java POST file errors

Tags: java, rest, post, angular, typescript

Ok then, I want to send file to server via POST. I am using angular2 function like this

```
 upload() {
    let inputEl = this.el.nativeElement.firstElementChild;
    if (inputEl.files.length == 0) return;

    let files :FileList = inputEl.files;
    const formData = new FormData();
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }

    this.http
        .post('MyURL', formData)
        .subscribe();

}

import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

request-options
    export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor () {
    super();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type','Multipart/form-data');
    this.headers.append('Accept','application/json');
     }
    }

The crud I want to make is

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' 'MyUrl'
```

The error looks like this

```
Request URL:MyUrl
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:35.154.2.84:80

Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1049
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 17 Nov 2016 21:15:39 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Request Header view source
accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fi;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:80082
content-type:Multipart/form-data
Host:MyUrl
Origin:http://evil.com/



Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryZXAikA6v0FHYrYii
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sku-test2.xls"; 
filename="sku-    test2.xls"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryZXAikA6v0FHYrYii--
```

I don't know If the problem is with that formData.append or what is wrong in code. Thanks for help.

EDIT:
code
:
"UNKNOWN_ERROR"
description
:
"org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: 
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found↵
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:111)↵
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85)↵
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)↵
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:928)↵    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)↵  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)↵  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)↵    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)↵ at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)↵    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)↵   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)↵  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)↵ at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)↵  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)↵   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)↵    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)↵ at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)↵    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)↵ at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)↵ at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)↵   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)↵ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)↵  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)↵Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found↵  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2856)↵ at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2692)↵   at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)↵   at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:92)↵ ... 32 more↵Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found↵    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:840)↵  at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)↵  at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)↵ at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2784)↵ ... 35 more↵"
errors
:
[]
message
:
"Internal error"
    enter code here
    enter code here